# MEAN Stack accessing id from URL

Tags: mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN Stack and is trying to do a simple project on it. I was trying to read 
a QR code and get the value of that QR code(which is an ID) and use that ID to fetch ID details from db.
 I have a controller where I wrote the code for scanning the QR code and then redirect the user to a new page where the details
 will be displayed.

```
window.location.href='http://localhost:3030/track/'+id;
```

On the redirecting page's controller I used the routeParams to get the id

```
angular.module('trController',[])
.controller('trCtrl',function($http,$routeParams){
   var id = $routeParams.id;
   $http.get('/api/track/'+id).then(function(data){
     console.log('data displayed');
   });
});
```

and passed it to my api.js file where i wrote the remaining code

```
router.get('/track/:id',function(req,res){
    var ID = req.params.id;
   //code for getting details from DB
  });
```

My router code is

```
 .when('/track/:id',{
    templateUrl : 'app/views/pages/track.html',
    controller: 'trCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'track'
  })
```

Sorry for the naive code as I'm new to this. What am i doing wrong? Plz help

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code...what is happening? the `id` is `undefined`? maybe the `trController` isn't the right name of the module? shouldn't be something like `trApp`?

Comment: @ElmerDantas I'm getting the id from QR code

Comment: what is the `id` value you're getting? I understood where the ID came from I just want to understand what is happening...what problem you're facing?